# Jquery autocomplete with category and multiple selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Is there already a solution for multiple select on jquery autocomplete with categories.? 
I couldn't seem to find one.

Does anyone know if there is already something like it..

Answer (score 0):

On the jQueryUI demos and documentation site you can find sourcecode for [categories](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple) and also for [multiple select](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple)

The only thing that is left to you is, to mix these two examples together and have your own multiple select category autocomplete

Comment: Did that and it works...but seems is not stable and am not sure if was the right way which I did...so.. was looking if there was an already built one which might be tested and used...

Comment: If it is not stable, post your efforts in a new question and include a sample hosted at for example http://jsfiddle.net